# Difficulty with MCMC implementation

Tags: modeling, python, markov-chain-montecarlo, fitting

I could really use some guided help! I'm having difficulty understanding an MCMC implementation in terms of modeling a data set. I'm working on generating parameters from stellar light curves, and was asked to look into implementing an MCMC algorithm. A large chuck on the code is written in Python, so I've been trying to use [emcee hammer](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/) to generate parameter fits. But going through the code, it's just not "clicking" how the method works.

I have a set of data (time vs flux) of two stars orbiting each other such that from our point of view, they eclipse. There are dips in the light curve to signify this. All I'm attempting to do is get the parameters of the system dependent on the characteristics of these dips.

In the emcee implementation, there are a few functions that I understand: the posterior function which, I believe, simply generates a data set given the set of parameters. Then there's a prior function which, I assume, is the function given a previous set of parameters. Somehow the algorithm chooses whether or not the jump to the posterior parameter set is to be done? I'm guessing that's what the use of the likelihood function is? To describe whether or not to take the jump?

I apologize, I'm quite confused on how this is to be implemented in terms a defined set of data.

Comment: Are you after a basic but general discussion of MCMC overall, a description of a specific kind of MCMC, or a specific discussion of it in relation to your problem?

Comment: Well, everything I find in terms of explanations seems to reference systems that already follow some distribution, like Monopoly. I was hoping for an explanation in terms of trying to fit a model to a preexisting set of data, which I cannot seem to find an example of. So, I suppose a discussion of how it relates to my specific _type_ of problem?

Comment: Then you'll need to explain your problem better.

Comment: The problem is the simple part: how do you use MCMC Hammer to generate a model, and then fit that model to a pre-existing data set, when the model has a large amount of parameters?